# OpenCv and OpenCL 1.1 embedded profile

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencl, gpu

I am trying to run OpenCV 3.2 with OpenCL 1.1 on imx6 device. OpenCV 2.4 works well with ocl on the board but ocv 3.2 can't detect the ocl. I know ocl usage has been changed with ocv 3.2.

Is my problem about the changing or something els? 
Is there any detailed documentation about that ocl difference between ocv 3 and 2?

I know these but need more details.
[1](http://answers.opencv.org/question/59566/what-is-the-difference-between-opencv-2411-and-300/), [2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html), [3](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html)

```
ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

if (!ocl::haveOpenCL())
{
std::cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << std::endl;
}
```

this returns "OpenCL is not available..." with OpenCV 3.2

Comment: How did you install OpenCV 3.2? From source or repo?

Comment: @Zindarod I found the recipe of it (.bb file) and compile with bitbake

Comment: Did you check if OpenCL option was on?

Comment: @Zindarod how to check it?

Comment: I don't have any experience with bitbake. If your bitbake recipe looked anything like this: http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_3.3.bb?h=master then see line 98. It checks for OpenCL package and sets the flag accordingly, you need to see if the flag is set or not.